# Is there a way to cast List Object into exact List Class in an generic function?

Tags: java, spring-boot, generics, objectmapper

I am coding in an Spring Boot Project and there was a lot of API with diffrent Request Param so I'm trying to write a generic function with mapper an request param into a list object, then cast it into a class like the code below

```
    public static <D> List<D> convertStringListToObject(String string) {
        if (string == null) return null;
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(string, new TypeReference<>() {
            });
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But the result is it can only return a list of Object not the list of D class like I'm expected. Does anyone have any ideas how to write this function?

Eddited:
Here is how I invoke it:

```
filterBlockRequestDto.setPopularFiltersList(ApiUtil.convertStringListToObject(filterBlockRequestDto.getPopularFilters()));
```

The FilterBlockRequestDto class

```
import lombok.*;

import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class FilterBlockRequestDto {
    Integer locationId;
    Integer projectId;
    String totalBudget;
    List<TotalBudgetDto> totalBudgetList;
    // The string was pass in Request param
    String popularFilters;
    List<PopularFiltersDto> popularFiltersList;
    Integer viewRating;
    Integer numberOfBed;
}
```

Comment: Please show how you are invoking it.

Comment: Oh: `new TypeReference<>() {}` isn't going to work. You need to pass in a `TypeReference<D>` as a parameter.

Comment: @AndyTurner Here is how i invoke it `filterBlockRequestDto.setPopularFiltersList(ApiUtil.convertStringListToObject(filterBlockRequestDto.getPopularFilters()));`. I have tried to add like you said before but the complier and IDE keep complain so I follow suggestion and the final result is above function. Can u provide me an example with pass type D in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to accept type reference as parameter so that the caller can provide the target class and as `TypeReference` is a subclass, generic type information will be available at runtime.

```
    public static <D> List<D> convertStringListToObject(String string, TypeReference<List<D>> typeReference) {
        if (string == null) return null;
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(string, typeReference);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to pass the type you want to deserialize your string to as well..

My approach on this would be something like this:

```
public static <T> T convertStringListToObject(String string, Class<T> clazz) {
    if (string == null) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
       return objectMapper.readValue(string, clazz);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and then  use this method as follows:

```
List<Model> models = 
    Arrays.asList(Mapper.convertStringListToObject(stringList, Model[].class));
```

Comment: It is still cast into an Object, not the exact Class I want it